# ZF3 ServiceManager ACL usable all over your application

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I'm facing an issue that I want to set a service (ACL) in the ServiceManager and be able to get/use it in the controllers and models all over my application.

I can register my ACL in my ServiceManager using Module.php it's onBootstrap() but there my issue starts. What is the best way to make it usable all over my application, so controllers, and models.

Then I was thinking about using a Trait and use that in my Abstract Model and Controller which are extented by all my controllers and models but this doesn't work, extending doesn't include the Trait.

Next my mind came up with about using a Factory, I tried to work something out using (confusing) examples but then I need to do this for both the controllers and models where a single trait which just does a `self::$sm = $sm;` is much more easy to maintain.

At the end I might looking for a (working) example so I can pick my ACL in my models where I want, or call a function like isAllowed() using prarent extending.

Maybe someone has better idea's or did the same which is able to help me out.

Comment: Why do you want to use ACL's in your models? What do you want to achieve with that, exactly? Because I think you are misusing ACL's

Comment: I need to set/unset userId's for my querybuidler as example when people are allowed to see all records or not. I don't see another way to accomplish that otherwise.

Comment: ACL's are used to access a given resource, not to determine if an user is allowed to see or not all records of a given table. You have two options then: create two different actions in your controller (which will lead to duplicates), or to create an `if/else` statemenet in the action to retrive your user's role.

Comment: Sure I can do it on Role but it's much nicer when I can give the user access based on isAllowed. It's likely undoable to do this on role to restrict users when you need to. This could be done using a reference table to the role but also that is actually the same as the ACL does but then the resources are already there and more flexible. At least that was my idea.

Comment: Normal way is to have your controllers extend the frameworks (ZF3) `AbstractController`. How about you create your own `AbstractAppController`? Pair it with your own `AbstractAppControllerFactory` which extends the default `InvokableFactory` (and injects your ACL service by default) ?

Comment: I have already my abstractAppController. I moved out the basic ACL for routes there and putted that check in onBootstrap, so Module.php which is still very light and it's much easier for redirecting and doesn't hit onDispatch. What do you mean extending InvokableFactory ? Do you have an example maybe ?

Comment: Can you show how you implement ACL in Module.php ?

Comment: What would that help to the current sitation ? Just get your ACL from where you have stored, it if the user is allowed for the resource otherwise redirect him ? I use `$e->getViewModel()->acl = $this->initAcl();` to store it if that is what you want to know ?

Comment: @Weins lucky I opened this question again. Should tag someone to get them a notification. [Example controller](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-mvc/blob/master/src/Controller/AbstractDoctrineActionController.php) with it's [ExampleFactory](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-mvc/blob/master/src/Factory/InvokableEntityManagerFactory.php). Use in `module.config.php` of a module under top-level key `controllers` and child `factories`, like so: `'controllers => ['factories'=> [ExampleController::class => InvokableEntityManagerFactory::class]]`